# Ao passar o mouse na opção o evento dispara continuamente

Tags: gml

Basicamente, eu estava fazendo um menu para meu jogo, ele é simples, apenas duas opções até agora ("Start", "Leave"). Até aí tudo bem, fui programar ele. Quando fui testar e passava o mouse por cima na opção, ela tocava sem parar, e só parava quando eu tirava da opção.

```
var isDespertar = false;

if isDespertar == true and place_meeting(x,y,obj_btn_start) {
    audio_play_sound(snd_change_option,1,0);
    show_debug_message("executou");
    var isDespertar = false;
} else {
    var isDespertar = true;
    show_debug_message("false")
    //audio_stop_sound(snd_change_option);
}
```

No mesmo obj_mira, há um step, que contém:

```
if place_meeting(x,y,obj_btn_start){
    obj_borda_start.visible = false;
    obj_borda_leave.visible = true;
    
    alarm_set(0,1);
} else if place_meeting(x,y,obj_btn_leave){
    obj_borda_leave.visible = false;
    obj_borda_start.visible = true;
} else {
    obj_borda_leave.visible = false;
    obj_borda_start.visible = false;
}
```

O primeiro código é um alarme, o place_meeting, se for true, vai executar o alarme.

Ele está no `obj_mira` (objeto da mira). O mais frustrante é que eu sei o porquê dele estar acontecendo, mas não sei como resolvê-lo. Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei imensamente agradecido!

Só para ficar mais "fácil" de entender como ele funciona:
Digamos que tenhamos um cubo, ele recebeu valor "amarelo", certo. Criemos uma condição, que executa se "cubo for roxo" (o que ele não, não é mesmo?), porém, se não for (else), o cubo irá se tornar roxo, assim, a ideia era que a variável se tornasse roxa, e o código começasse a ser lido como se o cubo fosse roxo, ou seja, ele tocaria o som, mas aí, no final do código, ele se tornaria verde, evitando que ficasse tocando toda hora o som (essa era a ideia), mas, bem... Não está funcionando :/... Já pedi ajuda em um Discord, mas não deu em nada.

Comment: Não entendo como o seu código funciona, se você não explicar os detalhes, como por exemplo o que contem em obj_btn_start ... recomendo que crie um exemplo minimo e BEM SIMPLES que possamos copiar facilmente e executar para entender aonde você falhou

Comment: Erro meu, desculpe. Não há nada no obj_btn_start, apenas no obj_mira. O que há no obj_mira é um step, que contém (não é só isso, claro, mas é basicamente isso que executa o alarme.

Irei colocar o código do step no post.

E, por último, há um evento de alarme, O que está no código é um alarme (0).

Answer (score 0):

Opa! Tive uma ideia, que basicamente era colocar em um create a variável, que receberia valor "true", depois, no step...:

```
if place_meeting(x,y,obj_btn_start) and global.ativardesativar == true {
    show_debug_message("ola");
    global.ativardesativar = false;
} else if !place_meeting(x,y,obj_btn_start) and global.ativardesativar == false {
    show_debug_message("tchau");
    global.ativardesativar = true;
}
```

Caso queiram, gostaria de pedir sugestões de como melhorá-lo.

Obrigado.